# Where can I find (plastic) IR-cut filter material?

Tags: filters, infrared

Is there any supplier of IR cut filter material? I.e., material that will **block** IR as opposed to allowing it to pass through? Preferably plastic, as I would like to be able to cut and shape it as appropriate.

Comment: Can you be more precise on the intended use of the filter ? Different filters will cut IR in different part of the spectrum.

Comment: @colin did you ever find a suitable filter material for this? I'm looking for it too.

Answer (score 1):

Try Edmund Scientific/Optics for prototyping materials.

Comment: https://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/shortpass-edge-filters/ir-cut-off-filters/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [something like this](http://www.lasersafetyindustries.com/Laser_Safety_Windows_s/1.htm) which is used for IR protection. I'm not sure how easy it is to cut cleanly you may have to experiment. Or you could go for a drop in filter (but they are not cheap, [here is one](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/572323-REG/Schneider_68_121066_6_6_x_6_6_Tru_Cut.html) for a cool $476.

Answer (score 0):

IR (and IR/UV) blocking filters are commonly used in astrophotography (since most telescopes with refractive elements are only corrected in the visual range, though there are some corrected out to nearIR/UV). I'm not aware of any plastic versions, though, but you may be able to get unmounted glass ones. A web search should pick up several suppliers - I know Baader Planetarium do mounted versions, not sure about unmounted, and I.m pretty sure all the other astrophotography filter manufacturers will do them too.